# Javascript (Remote include) : HTML Elements creation on-the-fly?

Tags: javascript, html, include

I'm trying to make a floating HTML button, along with the interaction on it *(like: Popping up a form when clicked)* by letting the people just EMBED some Javascript inside their Page.

So it's like, my HTML Elements should be generated on top of their page (at different domain) remotely.

For example, i have seen something like **Uservoice** Feedback Button and Form, it looks like:

[image]

We can have that Button generated on our site. The only thing we need to do is to embed their Javascript in our page:

```
<!-- USERVOICE -->
<script type="text/rocketscript">
  var uvOptions = {};
  (function() {
    var uv = document.createElement('script'); uv.type = 'text/javascript'; uv.async = true;
    uv.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'widget.uservoice.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(uv, s);
  })();
</script>
```

---

### I tried this

Then in order to achieve similar thing, i tried with my own 2 domains. On my Webpage at **www.domain-a.com**, i embed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 (function() { 
 var myButtonJS = document.createElement('script'); myButtonJS.type = 'text/javascript'; myButtonJS.setAttribute('defer', 'defer');
  myButtonJS.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'www.domain-b.com/myButton.js?3';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(myButtonJS, s);
 })();
</script>
```

On the **www.domain-b.com**, inside the `myButton.js`:

```
document.write('<div style="z-index:99999999;padding:5px 10px 2px 10px;border:1px solid #000000;position: fixed;bottom: 10px;right: 10px;_position:absolute;_top: expression(offsetParent.scrollTop+document.documentElement.offsetHeight-60);direction:ltr;background:#7fff00;">Click me!</div>');
```

But when i run, `http://www.domain-a.com`, the browser says:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

So please kindly let me know:

- What are the standard (proper) ways to achieve such ones?
- (In other words) how do i properly generate the HTML elements on top of remote sites, when they include the Javascript i provided to them?

Thanks all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the better way to do it is create the element on the fly from your externa js then load the script in the body of the html, that way you are sure that the document is loaded and then just hook in the body of document e.g:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
```

in your external script. then append your element there. :)

Comment: But then how do i bring another popup Form (bigger div box) ... upon clicking on this current generated DIV please?

Comment: add a click event handler for that, use button or a link, then add $('#id').on('click') handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can create A DOM element, use innerHTML to set its contents ant then attach to the DOM when the content is ready:

```
var myElement = document.createElement('div');
myElement.innerHTML = '<div style="z-index:99999999;padding:5px 10px 2px 10px;border:1px solid #000000;position: fixed;bottom: 10px;right: 10px;_position:absolute;_top: expression(offsetParent.scrollTop+document.documentElement.offsetHeight-60);direction:ltr;background:#7fff00;">Click me!</div>';
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.body.appendChild(myElement);
});
```

Comment: But then how do i bring another popup Form (bigger div box) ... upon clicking on this current generated DIV please?

Comment: You can use a similar approach. `myElement.addEventListener("click", function(){ //Create the form and attach to the dom like before })`